# Why MSVC compiler does not detect std::array out of bound access

Tags: c++, arrays

I replaced an old style array by a `std::array`, but then I realized compiler (at least MSVC) was doing less bound checking. Consider this code:

```
double myArray[10];
myArray[11] = 3.0;

std::array<double,10> myStdArray;
myStdArray[11] = 3.0;
```

Fo myArray, a warning is reported:

> warning C4789: buffer 'myArray' of size 80 bytes will be overrun; 8 bytes will be written starting at offset 88

For `myStdArray`, no warning is reported at all.

Is it a "bug" in the compiler or does the way `std::array` is implemented does not allow this kind of warning to be reported? If so, is it worth using `std::array` that appears to be less safe here...

Comment: You can use `std::get` to get compile-time errors if your index is known at compile time.

Comment: C++ has never had bounds-checking on arrays of any kind, and it never will. If you want bounds-checking you should use [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) instead. I do recommend `std::array` over plain C arrays for most cases though, not for "safety" but for ease of use.

Comment: The compiler can't see the internal implementation of `std::array`, or even its contract to the extent sufficient to provide the same message as for a native array.

Comment: @krzaq: That's definitely a nice proposal, as it even reports an error rather than a warning. And yes, I do know the index at compilation time (else I would not expect the compiler to report any error/warning ;-)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: MSVC compiler apparently does bounds-checking

Comment: Try passing e.g. `myArray` to a function and see the bounds-checking warning disappear. :) Also, note that it's a *warning* not an error.

Comment: @krzaq: By the way, your comment could become an acceptable answer.

Comment: @jpo38 -- The designers of `std::array` ensured that access to an element using `[ ]` incurred a runtime overhead equivalent to raw arrays.  If there were bounds checking, this would violate this goal, thus no bounds checking is done, and thereby you get undefined behavior.  If you want bounds checking for `std::array`, use `at()` instead of `[ ]`.  Then you would be guaranteed that an `std::out_of_range` exception is thrown, regardless of the compiler used.

Comment: @jpo38 [Here is g++ compiler using no bounds checking](http://ideone.com/Z28GJN).  You see that the buffer overrun is not detected.  Now [here is the same program using `std::array::at()`](http://ideone.com/3dhskM).  You get the exception thrown.  So `std::array` is less dangerous, or at least easier to diagnose boundary errors than using raw arrays, since there is no `at()` function to use on raw arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get) to get a guaranteed error if your access is out of bounds. The index must be known at the compile time, of course.

```
std::array<double,10> myStdArray;
std::get<9>(myStdArray) = 3.0; // ok
std::get<11>(myStdArray) = 3.0; // error
```

---

As to the other part of your question: this might be conjecture on my part, but the standard library should be considered "magical" in the way that the compiler knows its contracts and there's nothing making it impossible for it to perform fact checking.

This is easily provable with the following example. Both clang and gcc elide the `memset` call in favour of direct write in the following function:

```
void zero_int(int* ptr)
{
  memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(int));
}
```

[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/wo6mVA)

So, to the best of my knowledge there's nothing preventing the compiler from emitting warnings in your code, except for potential implementation difficulty/cost.

Answer (score 7):

`myArray[11]` is language built-in functionality which the compiler knows about and which the compiler can warn for.

`myStdArray[11]` is short for `myStdArray.operator[](11)`, which is a function call where `11` is well in the parameter type's range. Warning for this requires looking into `operator[]`'s function body, which is something that typically only happens if the function gets inlined.

Furthermore, vendor extensions may make `myStdArray.operator[](11)` well-defined, e.g. as aborting the program in debug mode, and in such implementations it's *very* difficult to get a useful compile-time warning.

However, with such extensions, the added run-time safety may still outweigh the lack of compile-time warnings.